# Upgrade 2.2.6 - 2.3.1 -> Table staging.queu doe not exist

Tags: database, magento2.3

I have followed all procedures to update correctly.
After composer is updated and we run 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade' we get a strange error. Please see image attached.

Error is Base Table or view not found:1146 Table 'ortlieb_staging.queue' doesn't exit.

So I have trouble in understanding how to solve this.
Creating a 'queue' table is not the solution according to me.

If somebody can advise on what to do to solve this that would be great. 
Please note all update steps before the 'upgrade' command were done according to documentation of Magento.

[image]

Comment: I upgraded 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 last week and everything was fine.  However i made sure composer was fully updated before i upgraded magento.  Sorry it is not an answer, but i wanted to confirm it is possible to update between those versions.  I also had to delete all of the added extensions from /app and put them back with the new versions, not just overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we managed to solve this. However we had to hire an external developer so we are not 100% sure where the reason was but in the end it could be solved by someone with some more knowledge on Magento then I had.

Comment: I must say I simply added the missing tables (there are 3, queue, queue_message and queue_message_status) by hand for one customer who ran into this as well. Simply have a look at vendor/magento/module-mysql-mq/etc/db_schema.xml and add the tables accordingly.. Too difficult? export the tables (including the constraints!) from a fresh install...